# How to find text within brackets with some exceptions by regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex `/^\[(text:\s*.+?\s*)\]/mi` that currently works in capturing text in brackets that begin with `text:`. Here is an example where it works:

```
[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets.]
```

Now, I would like to add an exception so that it allows certain brackets like in the case below:

```
[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also include ![](/some/path)]
```

Basically, I need it to allow the `![](/some/path)` brackets in the match.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

Here are some cases where the text inside the brackets should be matched:

```
[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also include ![](/some/path)]

[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also include ![](/some/path) and some more text]

[text: ![](/some/path)]

![text: cat]
```

Here are some cases where it should not match:

```
[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also include ![invalid syntax](/some/path)]

[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also include ![] (/some/path)]

[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also include ! [](/some/path)]

[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also include ! [] (/some/path)]
```

Comment: What exactly is making those brackets special that they should be matched? Is it the `!` before them? Is it the fact that they are corresponding opening/closing brackets? Could those brackets be nested more deeply?

Comment: What flavor of regex?

Comment: We need to know what "flavor" of [regex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) you're using.

Comment: Yes, it's the `!` before the brackets that makes it special.

Comment: Not sure what flavor it's in but it's for RoR. (rails 3.2, ruby 2.2)

Comment: @AllenLiu you should tag your question with the programming language. For example, the `/m` modifier has a very different meaning in Ruby (this regex would not match newlines in any other flavor)

Comment: @Mariano - Done! Thanks.

Comment: Suppose instead of `![](/some/path)` it were `![cat](/some/path)` or `![text: cat](/some/path)`.  What would you want returned in those cases?

Comment: That's helpful. Is it `![](/'` or `![]('` that determines whether it's a match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so you want to allow either

- a character that's not a bracket or
- the sequence `![]`

between the starting and ending bracket. This gives you the regex

```
/^\[(text:[^\[\]]*(?:!\[\][^\[\]]*)*)\]/mi
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           # Start of line
\[          # Match [
(           # Start of capturing group
 text:      # Match text:
 [^\[\]]*   # Match any number of characters except [ or ]
 (?:        # Optional non-capturing group:
  !\[\]     #  Match ![]
  [^\[\]]*  #  Match any number of characters except [ or ]
 )*         # Repeat as needed (0 times is OK)
)           # End of capturing group
\]          # Match ]
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pA6sI4/1).

Comment: If you don't use `.` in the regex, you don't need the `m` identifier.

Comment: @sawa: Ah, the `ruby` tag was added after my answer. Luckily, the meaning of `^` is unambiguous in Ruby :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use your regex, slightly modified and simplified.

```
str =<<_
[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also includes ![](/some/path)]
and other stuff
_

r = /
    ^       # match beginning of string
    \[text: # match string
    .+?     # match one or more characters lazily
    \]      # match right bracket
   /imx      # case indifferent (i), multiline (m) and extended/free-spacing (x) modes

PLACEHOLDER = 0.chr
SUBSTITUTE_OUT = '![](/'

puts str.gsub(SUBSTITUTE_OUT, PLACEHOLDER).
  scan(r).
  map { |s| s.gsub(PLACEHOLDER, SUBSTITUTE_OUT) }

[text: here is my text that is
captured within the brackets
and also includes ![](/some/path)]
```

Note that, in the regex, `\s*.+?\s*` is the same as `.+?` and (as @sawa noted) you could replace `.+?` with `[^\]]+` in which case you would not need multiline mode.

Edit: I updated `SUBSTITUTE_OUT` in light of the OP's edit of the question. This illustrates one advantage of this approach: the regex is not affected by changes to the inner matching text.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a [negative lookbehind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html) in this regex to assert that a closing bracket doesn't immediately follow an opening bracket:

```
^\[(text:.+?)(?<!\[)\]
```

Here's the walk-through.

```
^           # Start of line anchor.
\[          # Match opening bracket '['
(           # Start capturing group 1. 
text:       # Match 'text:'
.+?         # Match any character one or more times lazily.
)           # End capturing group 1. 
(?<!        # Begin negative lookbehind.
\[          # '[' must not preceed the next match.
)           # End negative lookbehind.
\]          # Match closing bracket.
```

Here's a [demo](http://rubular.com/r/nNGElegJr5).

Comment: Clever! Note that `\s*` doesn't add anything. If you write the regex in extended mode (see my answer) you don't have to repeat yourself (recognizing that extended mode cannot always be used).

Comment: Nice; I use verbose Python for documentation/readability, but wasn't sure how to do it in Ruby. And good point about the unnecessary `\s*`--I've updated my answer.

Comment: Don't forget that SO members are not notified of comments directed to them if the member's name is not in the comment (e.g., @CarySwoveland or just @Cary).

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand how the new line character is relevant to what you describe, so I removed `^`.

```
/\[(text:(?:[^\[\]]|!\[\][/\w]+)+)\]/i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the following regex:

```
^\[(text:.*?(?<!\[))\]
```